# PHP Sorting results of a Loop and displaying onscreen

Tags: php, sorting

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction with a coding issue Im having.

I am running a while loop in PHP comparing a post code to another and each run of the loop generates distance data. What Id like to do is then sort this data and display it.

Usually I'd throw everything into a MySQL database then sort that way but I think thats over kill.

Here's an example of the loop :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    $info = get_driving_information($_POST['customerpostcode'], $row[instructor_postcode]); 

echo $row['instructor_name']  . " - " . $info['distance'];  
}
```

I know this is probably PHP 101 but Ive never had to do anything like this before and am not sure how.

Thanks in advance for reading,

Rik

Comment: look in this [link](http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/php/4-functions-to-help-you-master-php-arrays-data-manipulation/) it might help you

Comment: Use mysql for sorting is more efficient. Why not?

Comment: @webbiedave I think we all assumed distance but to be honest your question is completely valid; it's not specified anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you mean:

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $info = get_driving_information($_POST['customerpostcode'], $row[instructor_postcode]); 
    $row['distance'] = $info['distance']; // store it in the array

    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Then use `usort` to sort the `$rows` array by the distance key.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $info = get_driving_information($_POST['customerpostcode'], $row['instructor_postcode']);
  $data[$row['instructor_name']] = $info['distance'];
}

asort($data);

foreach ($data as $instructor => $distance) echo "$instructor - $distance<br />\n";
```

This will sort by instructor name. If you need to sort by distance, just reverse the way data is stored in the temporary array, I.E. `$data[$row['distance']] = $info['instructor_name'];`.

This will not work if the value you use as the temporary array key appears more than once, for that you would have to use [array_multisort()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php).

```
$data = $instructors = $distances = array();

for ($i = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $i++) {
  $info = get_driving_information($_POST['customerpostcode'], $row['instructor_postcode']);
  $instructors[$i] = $row['instructor_name'];
  $distances[$i] = $row['distance'];
  $data[$i] = array('instructor'=>$row['instructor_name'],'distance'=>$info['distance']);
}

array_multisort($instructors,SORT_DESC,$distances,SORT_ASC,$data);

foreach ($data as $entry) echo "{$entry['instructor']} - {$entry['distance']}<br />\n";
```

Comment: This solution will break if an instructor appears more than once in the result set.

Comment: @Brian True, but looking at the orginal code I was assuming this would not happen. It is foolish to make such assumptions, I admit...

Answer (score 1):

What I'd recommend here is storing each distance result in an array and then apply a sort to the array. For example:

```
$distances = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    $info = get_driving_information($_POST['customerpostcode'], $row[instructor_postcode]); 

    $distances[$info['distance']] = $row['instructor_name']  . " - " . $info['distance'];  
}

if(ksort($distances)) {
    foreach($distances as $key=>$value) {
          echo $value;
    }
}
```

Note that my solution will not work for you if an exact distance appears more than once in the array; If that seems likely then you might need a different array-based solution.

For more information on array sorting, see [Sorting Arrays](http://us.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) in the PHP manual.

Comment: Yours will break if a distance appears more than once, which I think is more likely :-D (and I added a missing `$` in your code)

Comment: I actually noted the distance issue in my answer, but thanks nonetheless for pointing out what I already had.

Comment: @DaveRandom if the distances are whole numbers, then I agree it is very likely. If they are floats, then I don't think it's very likely at all (unless the same input is being passed into the user's method repeatedly)

Comment: even with floats it is quite likely, it's quite obviouse that the distance is calculated using postcodes, so all you need is two similar pairs of postcodes to get exactly the same results even if floats have unlimited precision.

Comment: @Ivan good point, I hadn't considered that, but obviously using postal codes rather than lat/long pairs or exact addresses will increase the likelihood of distance collisions.

Comment: I think to be on the safe side this is a job for `array_multisort()` and have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @DaveRandom Yes, I was thinking the same.

Answer (score 0):

This will work even if you have same instructor_name or distances several time in the array. Additionally buy modifying cmp() function you can sort whole thing by any other criteria.

```
$drivers = array();//initialising an array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $info = get_driving_information($_POST['customerpostcode'], $row[instructor_postcode]); 
  $drivers[]=row;//adding new item to array
}

$drivers = usort($drivers,'cmp'); // sorting array using custom comparison  function "cmp()"

foreach ($drivers as $driver) //printing results
  echo $driver['instructor_name']  . " - " . $driver['distance'];  


//custom comparison function
function cmp($a, $b) //returns +1 if $a > $b, -1 if $a < $b, else returns 0
{
  if ($a['distance']>$b['distance'])
    return 1;
  if ($a['distance']<$b['distance'])
    return -1;
  return 0;
  //quicker solution is to "return $a['distance']-$b['distance'];"
}
```